# Content hide in Navigation Bar - One Page Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on website called  : [denimistcompany.com](http://denimistcompany.com)

issue is that that menu is link with elements "id" , and now when someone clicks on about us , the main heading called Welcome to Denimist ... got hidden in navigation background.

is that possible we somehow start the the section from the point we like as all links is having same problem.

THanks

Comment: Yeah, you use a smooth scroll script for those links currently. Instead of scrolling to the anchor point on the page, grab the header height and subtract that from the top position of the anchor point and scroll there instead. If you want help implementing it, reproduce your problem on SO so we have a [mcve] that we can work with instead of just linking to your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping in mind that your navigation bar height is 90px and it's fixed, you have to use pseudo-element:

```
#aboutus::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -90px;
}
```

Or alternatively can try this as well:

```
#aboutus {
  padding-top: 90px;
  margin-top: -90px;
}
```

Just checked on your website, and it works great.